# SQLite concurrency issue a deal breaker?

Tags: mysql, database, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

I am looking at databases for a home project (ASP.NET MVC) which I might host eventually. After reading a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840454/which-database-should-i-use-for-home-project-use) on Stack Overflow I have decided to go with MySQL.

However, the easy of use & deployment of SQLite is tempting, and I would like to confirm my reasons before I write it off completely.

My goal is to maintain user status messages (like Twitter). This would mean mostly a single table with user-id/status-message couples. Read / Insert / Delete operation for status message. No modification is necessary.

After reading the following paragraph I have decided that SQLite can't work for me. I DO have a simple database, but since ALL my transaction work with the SAME table I might face some problems.

*SQLite uses reader/writer locks on the entire database file. That means if any process is reading from any part of the database, all other processes are prevented from writing any other part of the database. Similarly, if any one process is writing to the database, all other processes are prevented from reading any other part of the database.*

Is my understanding naive? Would SQLite work fine for me? Also does MySQL offer something that SQLite wouldn't when working with ASP.NET MVC? Ease of development in VS maybe?

Comment: Have you considered SQL Server Compact Edition? With some forethought you can change that to a full SQL Server later if you need to, but SQLCE doesn't have the locking problems that SQLite does.

Comment: How many users will your application have? How many of them do you expect to be actually accessing your app at the same time?

Comment: @ninjalj, not many to be honest. The project is more of a learning experience than a business decision, so I was looking at something that is "correct" rather than "workable". Do I make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to wait half a month, the next SQLite release intends to support [write-ahead logging](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html), which should allow for more write concurrency.

Comment: Depends on your timeframe. If you don't expect heavy usage in the next two weeks (it being a home project and all), you could just develop for SQLite and update the library then.

Or just develop in MySQL and port to SQLite later if the next release proves worthwhile. If your database code is sane, a one-table app should be easy to translate.

Comment: How many processes are going to be writing to the DB? If it's a single front end that handles multiple requests and does the updates then SQLite is fine. If you have multiple front ends all talking to the same DB then you probably want a full DBMS anyway

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to get even the simple concurrency SQLite claims to support to work - even after asking on SO a couple of times.

**Edit**
Since I wrote the above, I **have** been able to get concurrent writes and reads to work with SQLite.  It appears I was not properly disposing of NHibernate sessions - putting Using blocks around all code that created sessions solved the problem.
**/Edit**

But it's probably fine for your application, especially with the Write-ahead Logging that user380361 mentions.

Small footprint, single file installation, fast, works well with NHibernate, free, public domain - a very nice product in almost all respects!