# how to make windows startup project with many methods running at the same time in the background

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, startup, background-process

I have explained my project below and asked some questions with "My Question-"  tag.

I have working on a project. At the time of windows logon page if I enter a wrong password my cam should take the picture, If I open regedit my system should take a screen shot and save these images in C:\Windows\system32\new folder (I tried a lot making this work with the help of manifest files but failed everytime) and emails it whenever finds an internet connection

I have a form based app because I didn't find any other way to capture image from webcam directly but taking input from pictureBox1.Image.

My cam, screenshot,email (didn't find a way to autocheck if has internet connection available or not) and 3 events checker for "firewall enable/disable, windows logon failure , regedit event called" are done and they are working good.

What I need to do is to assemble these codes to work as an app and running in the background continuously from the time of windows startup to shutdown

To validate positive events I need to make a desktop based db ("My Question"- still figuring out either to choose sql or localdatabase in c#. Please also tell me a suitable solution.I have to delete all the entries from the db once a day is over). The db would contain the following columns (event id, event name,  event timestamp).

I want my app to check if this very event exists in the db then it should ignore the event generated on windows event log else it should make a new row with the db columns and it should do the following actions based on the event like taking webcam pic or screenshot.

"My Question"- I want my app to be live at the time of windows logon page. A lot of programs start later when you are authenticated but I need my program to be live at the time of logon page. Do I have to make 1 or many services? or multi-threaded? because in the typical form based app you can only call one function at a time and wait for it to return something or perform some task/action and then you call the second third whatever.

"My Question"- Do I need to use the backgroundworker in c#

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of things going on here for one question.

You can put all your code in a background service that gets started at boot time.  There is a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here to show you how to do that (along with a million other sites).

Addressing some of the other issues you listed:

Google is your friend...

Webcam - Found a quick reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx) and [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Webcam-Capture-50295c7f)

File Modification - Another SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes)

SQL vs. Other Database - Not sure you need anything elaborate here, probably something you can put together pretty quickly.  Another SO thread addressing that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572804/single-user-database-options)

Good Luck!

Comment: That was no nice of you:) I appreciate it.

Comment: I don't find any material on this site http://code.google.com/p/multi-service-install/